# Automated polygon sliver removal

Tags: topology

I am in the process of cleaning a large polygon dataset. This dataset represents the extents of an electrical network from a substation.

The polygons have not been created correctly and there are over 2800 slivers of varying sizes and lengths between each polygon boundary.

Compounding the issues I am having there are a number of other “feeder” polygons representing transmission lines. So these polygons can be many kilometres long and pass through more than one of the polygons I am working with. These transmission polygons are removed and leave a sliver crossing multiple polygons.

I am looking for a way to repeatedly and automatically remove these slivers to provide a clean dataset to stakeholders.

I would usually:

- Create a large bounding box around all polygons
- Erase the polygons from this bounding box
- Merge the remaining polygons into the main dataset and select them
- Run an Eliminate on this dataset and sanity check the result

Problem here are the polygons crossing multiple areas. As well as a few other issues, e.g. the `eliminate` in QGis removes some of the polygons I want to keep, resulting in a final output with missing data.

My new methodology in theory (at least I think it should work).

- Once the erase is completed, I densify the polygon and extract the
  vertices
- I created Thiessen Polygons from these vertices
- I run the erase again on the newly created polygons, using the main
  dataset I want to fix.
- I then proceed with the regular process.

I haven’t been able to get this to finish.

I have been using QGis, but I have access to ArcGIS Pro if needed as well as FME. I am comfortable using Python. I am running a Windows Machine and do not have access to Mac OS / Linux.

My question is: are there any other techniques I can try to improve on the topology of this dataset in a way that is repeatable and possibly scripted?

Comment: Did you try pprepair ? https://github.com/tudelft3d/pprepair . I have a work in progress R package to also do this. Let me know if you want to give a try, it's really experimental (pushed this morning on Gitlab) but you can try the pprepair cpp tools first and if you want to give a try in R, I can share the link and help you

Comment: Thank you @dickoa I will have a look at pprepair. It sounds like it is a great tool...but will only run on ubuntu. At the moment I do not have access to Mac, Linux / uBuntu..but will try anyway, to see what it can do.

Comment: Just wondering. Did it work ?

Comment: Unfortunately the policy of my organisation didnt allow me to get it installed. I ended up having to use FME and then some manual intervention to get it to work. This is still a work in progress.